# How can I make AutocompleteInput scrollable inside a SelectArrayInput?

Tags: react-admin

Ever since AutoComplete was removed from material-ui, the list isn't scrollable. Below is a snippet from the yester years which used to work.

```
<ReferenceArrayInput label="Parts" source="partId" reference="parts" 
allowEmpty>
    <AutocompleteInput optionText="name"
       options={{ listStyle: { overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: 200}}} />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

As per the new documentation of react-admin, AutocompleteInput renders a meterial-ui TextField component. Use the `options` attribute to override any of the TextField attributes.

I don't seem to find a way to make the list scrollable or set a maxHeight to the list.

Please help